# Convert point cloud data into laserscan in ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, laserscan, ros-indigo, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What the way to convert point cloud data from Kinect sensor into laserscan in ROS Indigo?
In Electric i'd made it via pointcloud_to_laserscan from turtlebot-robot stack.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188444/convert-point-cloud-data-into-laserscan-in-ros-indigo/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS Indigo you can find this functionality on the package [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan).

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2014-07-31**:
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) package. However, it uses the depth image provided by your sensor (in your case, the Kinect) as opposed to the point cloud (practically the same thing).

I had some trouble with the distortion model from my sensor when I used it. Ensure that your camera_info provides all the parameters that the package requires.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2014-07-31**:
I see. Thanks!